# Display user friendly msg on UI in case of error in SQL Server operation

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, error-handling

I have a query. When we are dealing with Oracle DB and if any error appears, the system error message will contain an `ORA` "marker". Is there anything similar for SQL Server error messages?

My requirement is I need to display user friendly error message in the UI in case of an issue with a database operation.

For Oracle databases, I am checking in code like shown here:

```
if (error.message.includes('ORA').toLowerCase()) {
    return res.send("DB related issue occurred while performing an operation."))
}
```

I need to do something equivalent for SQL Server. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you catching these error messages? Normally you know they are a database error because you catch it in a try/catch block around a database operation.

Comment: If you're programming in a .NET Framework language, like C#, you should be using exception handling, e.g.: `try { ... } catch (SqlException) { return "Oops, database error!" }`